# UTF support for oracle procedure when calling by JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, unicode, utf-8, procedure

One of our oracle stored procedures loads a file data to a table. We are calling that procedure in tomcat web app by jdbc. The problem we have is that the procedure does not handle the Unicode characters correctly. It stores the Unicode data with weird characters in the table. Since I don't have control over procedure code, is there any way I can modify my java code, change tomcat config or alter table to make the procedure read and load file with Unicode characters correctly?

What is the database and national character set? - Oracle(Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production), AL16UTF16

What character set is the file encoded using? - ANSI

How is the file being loaded? -by UTL_FILE. Procedure and table are not external to each other

Are you loading data into a VARCHAR2 column? Or an NVARCHAR2 column? - NVARCHAR2

How do you know that the problem occurs in loading the data rather than in retrieving the data? - Actually I don't. I have no access to db logs

Are you using dump to view..? No - I use a Productivity Software Toad

Comment: What is the database and national character set?  What character set is the file encoded using?  How is the file being loaded?  Is the stored procedure calling an external table?  Using `UTL_FILE`?  Something else?  Are you loading data into a `VARCHAR2` column?  Or an `NVARCHAR2` column?  How do you know that the problem occurs in loading the data rather than in retrieving the data?  Are you using `dump` to view the data that is actually stored in the table to confirm that the binary values are not what you expect?